# compiler-error: empty parameter field

Tags: java

```
public class learningJava
{
    public static String last4(String s)
    {
       String str = "something";
       //int length = str.length();
       String substr = str.substring(str.length() - 4);
       if (str.length() < 4)
       {
           return str;
       }
       return str.substring(str.length() - 4);
    }  

}
```

Comment: and what is the question based on that code?

Comment: I'm guessing he is calling this method (in code not shown), and he is not passing in a string.

Comment: sorry guys, forgot to post main thing...Yeah, compiler returns error: empty parameter field. Why is it so? It says no syntax errors...

Comment: Use camelcase in your class names, i.e. `public class LearningJava`

Comment: post the main thing...

Comment: I meant forgot to ask question

Comment: There's definitely more code required to cause that output. Can you create a small _yet complete_ example and post it?

Comment: Thank you VolkerK! Just realized that was trying to implement something totally incomplete!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function wants a parameter as `String s`. Probably you are getting this error because you are using this function somewhere without adding parameter.

When you want to use this function you have to use a code like:

```
String y;

String x = last4(String y);
```

In fact you don't need to use that, your function doesn't need any parameters so you can delete String s and use your function like that.

```
public class learningJava
{
    public static String last4()
    {
       String str = "something";
       //int length = str.length();
       String substr = str.substring(str.length() - 4);
       if (str.length() < 4)
       {
           return str;
       }
      return str.substring(str.length() - 4);
    }  

}
```

and you can use it as like that

```
String y;
y = last4();
```

Or if you want to use other string then "something" in your function, you can change it like that:

```
public class learningJava
{
    public static String last4(String y)
    {

       //int length = y.length();
       String substr = y.substring(y.length() - 4);
       if (y.length() < 4)
       {
           return y;
       }
      return y.substring(y.length() - 4);
    }  

}
```

and you can call this function by using a parameter as like my first example.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gloominess for such in-depth answer.

Comment: I am glad if it solved your problem and thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

you have not used the s parameter passed into the last4 method. 
Also, the classname should start with an uppercase letter. So it should be *LearningJava*.

I think what you want is something like this:

```
public class LearningJava {
    public static String last4(String s) {
        if(s.length() < 4) {
            return s;
        }
        String subs = s.substring(s.length() - 4);
        return subs;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println(LearningJava.last4("something"));
    }
}
```

Note that you want to execute the if(s.length() < 4)  part before using the substring method. Otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks Sameer got it.